# How do you configure a direct serial PPP connection for Connection Manager on Windows Mobile?

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce

We're trying establish a direct serial PPP connection on several Symbol Windows Mobile devices, including MC75, MC9590 running Windows Mobile 6.1 and 6.5.  Have used the RAS APIs in the past with some success, but have found that RasHangUp() will hang and never return when the device is removed from its cradle. In response to a case opened by Motorola, Microsoft's response was that RAS deprecated and suggested we try using Connection Manager instead - yeah just that helpful.  While the APIs are pretty straight forward, there are no examples I can find on configuring a direct serial connection (or Destination, Microsoft's term).  I'm skeptical RAS is deprecated as it still appears in the MSDN documentation with no such indication.

I've examined MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb737593.aspx, and the XML examples appear to be specific to cellular connections.

I'd appreciate any clue about the best direction to take here, thanks.

Comment: When you use RAS, are setting all of your various parameters through code, or do you configure it via the device control panel?

Comment: In the past we used RasDial and created the phonebook entry using code.  We extracted the registry and added it to our CAB files for install.  Because of problems with Symbol devices blocking forever on RasHangUp we are attempting to use the Connection Manager instead of RAS - Microsoft's recommendation.  I've not found any documentation on setting up a direct PPP connection over a serial port.

Comment: Connection manager is just a layer on indirection on top of all the possible networks and comm technologies available.  Based on what you want to connect to, Connection Manager is supposed to establish a WiFi or Cellular or Modem etc connection for you to use.

Comment: I haven't done much with RAS so YMMV, but I have had to setup connection-manager related configuration before.  I find the provisioning XML that sets connection manager (and other stuff) up is almost impossible to hand-craft.  It really helps to start with a system configured how you want and then scrape it into XML.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean configured via the control panel UI.  There's no direct serial option there.

Comment: Have you tried using your code to create your desired RAS settings and then scraping the config XML to see if they are captured or not?  Long shot...

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.  There are several other registry values involved in HKLM\comm\ConnMgr.  The [MC75\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Comm\ConnMgr\Providers\{7C4B7A38-5FF7-4bc1-80F6-5DA7870BB1AA}\Connections\] appear to map to the phonebook entries in [MC75\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Comm\RasBook].  I may try to backdoor our direct serial connection my using the UI to make one that dials GPRS, and then swap the the phonebook entry out.  Let you know.